# How to pass the id of a class instance?

Tags: objective-c, nsthread

My use case is that I'm trying to start a thread where the destination target object is a class instance.  The compiler is giving me an error (Unexpected interface name '': expected expression) when I try to do something like the following:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(thing:) toTarget:AClass withObject:nil];

@implementation AClass
+(void)thing:(id)arg {
// etc....
}
@end
```

How do I setup this scenario?  Or rather, how do I get the id of the class instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[AClass class]`. Every class responds to the `+class` method and returns itself.

Comment: But doesn't that return an instance of Class?  Is Class a superclass of the object (thus castable to id)?

Comment: @Brett: No. `Class` is just a typedef for the obj-c runtime type that represents a class. It is not actually the name of a class.

Comment: @Brett: Basically, `Class` is just like `id` except it represents any obj-c class instead of any objc- instance.